# mysql matching encrypted values

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

When I run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName = AES_ENCRYPT('value','SecretKey')
```

I'm returned an empty set, even though there are rows in the db that match the search query.

What would the correct syntax for something like this look like?

Comment: set it up with a sample of how it got there. Should take about 5 minutes.

Comment: Sorry? Don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com to create an MCVE, @tdrsam, and share the link.  If you are storing the encrypted value in a `VARCHAR` instead of a `VARBINARY`, a fairly common error, that would also explain the problem -- you can't do that.  `AES_ENCRYPT()` returns binary data, not character data.  Not all possible byte patterns are valid characters.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of sqlfiddle. I've heard of jsfiddle (ofcourse) but not the sql one. Will try to find time for it tomorrow.

Comment: So, I tried making a fiddle but I don't seem to be able to insert an encrypted password to the schema. I can insert a non-encrypted password, but this code gives me a syntax error `INSERT INTO users ('email', 'password') VALUES ('test1@test.com', AES_ENCRYPT('test','FJEU65412335867412563FECSADF961287535');`

Comment: SqlFiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ad4db/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName = AES_ENCRYPT(columnName,'SecretKey')='value'
```